# Sets of measure zero on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is there anything wrong with what I have written here?

Let $D$ be a non-empty subset of the real numbers, with Lebesgue measure $0$.
Say $x$  is in $D$. Since $D$ has measure $0$, it cannot contain any intervals. Therefore,
for any $d > 0$, we know $(x - d,x + d)$ is not contained in $D$. Hence, for any $d > 0$, there is a real number $z$ in $(x - d,x + d)$ so that $z$ is not in $D$.

Comment: Format the question properly.

Comment: Thanks, @ccroth

Comment: The argument is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: in conclusion, " any neighbourhood of $x$ has an real number that is not in D"

Comment: In fact, each such interval $(x-d,\,x+d)$ contains continuum many points not in $D.$ The weaker version "uncountably many" involves very little additional work (make use of the fact that countable sets have measure zero), and one way to get "continuum many" makes use of $G_{\delta}$ regularity of Lebesgue measure and the fact that uncountable $F_{\sigma}$ sets have cardinality continuum (which itself follows immediately from the fact that uncountable closed sets have cardinality continuum, which in turn follows from the Cantor-Bendixson theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement is correct: a set $D$ of measure $0$ (a null set) in the reals (or any so-called strictly positive measure space, where $\mu(U) >0$ for any $U$ that is open and non-empty) has empty interior, or $D^\complement$ is dense.